# Align items using flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a requirement as shown below:

```
|[]                  [][]|
```

One element at left side of the viewport and two elements on right side of the viewport. To learn `display: flex`, I am trying this layout without wrapping the elements.

Is this layout possible with flexbox?

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child child--left"></div>
    <div class="child child--right"></div>
    <div class="child child--right"></div>
</div>
```

I tried using `align-items` and `align-self` but no use. Please help.

CSS:

```
.parent{
     display: flex;  // flexbox
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `margin-left:auto` in the div you need in the right side:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

.child {
  flex: 0 0 20px;
  border: solid 1px green;
}

.child--right {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child child--right"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: nice. where have you seen this trick? I am just asking so that I can learn more about it. Thanks.

Comment: Here, in stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32551291/in-css-flexbox-why-are-there-no-justify-items-and-justify-self-properties

Comment: arghh.. so my post is duplicate. Should have searched better. Anyway thanks :)

Comment: I could not remember where I had seen, I thought it was css-trick but was here

Answer (score 1):

you need to use a `spacer` defined as `flex:auto;` in order to align the flex-boxes as intended: **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/dp2r8hdx/)**

**CSS**

```
.parent{
  display:flex;
}
.spacer{
  flex:auto;
}
```

and your **HTML** would be:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child child--left"></div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="child child--right"></div>
    <div class="child child--right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is nice. I will use this in my project. but I felt blonfu's answer is good because it handles in css. +1'ed :)

Comment: you're welcome, this is what I always use in my projects

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex to fill a space

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  background: purple;
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
}
.item {
  background: orange;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 12.5px;
}
.filler {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="filler"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

You'll notice I've added a div with the class `filler` and set it to have `flex-grow: 1;` This means that div will always take up the remaining space.

Answer (score 0):

Applying: `margin-<direction>: auto` on the child of a flex item will essentially float the item in the opposite direction (with none of the complications of `float`).

```
.child--right {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this without using an extra filler element is to use auto-margins.

**CSS**

```
.child--left {
    margin-right: auto; /* <== here's the auto margin */
}
```

It will add a margin to the right of `.child--left` which will fill up the available space within `.parent` (essentially acting like there's a filler element between the left and right children, but actually without the filler element)

Answer (score -1):

## HTML

```
   <div class="parent">
        <div class="child child--left"><div class="box"></div></div>
        <div class="child child--right"><div class="box"></div></div>
        <div class="child child--right"><div class="box"></div></div>
    </div>
```

## css

```
   .parent{
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
    }

    .box{
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      background: #333;
      margin: 20px
    }
```

Source: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rittamdebnath/315wps5g/